# How do I create a Google Maps link with both query and center parameters?

Tags: google-maps

I want to link to both the query or top result of a query on Google Maps, while centering on a longitude and latitude, like this:

https://maps.google.com/?q=Yosemite&center=37.7388,-119.57

However, if this is clicked, &center=... is discarded, and Google only looks for and displays Yosemite.

Is there a way to include the lat&long and the query in the search box, as well?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** replace *center=* with *ll=*

**Source:** have a look at this http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters it explains the supported query parameters very well.